# How to use the complete property in velocity.js to trigger localscroll

Tags: jquery, triggers, jquery-events, scrollto, velocity.js

I am using [velocityjs](http://julian.com/research/velocity/), [localscroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) (which needs [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)).

I have a form that is hidden by default. I am using an anchor tag that when clicked, will show the form.

**html**

```
<a href="#myForm" class="button" id="show">Show the form</a>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#show').click(function (event) {
    $('#myForm')
    .velocity('slideDown', {'duration': 2000})
    .velocity({'opacity': 1}, {
        'complete': function () {
             $('#myForm').localScroll({
                 'target': 'body',
                 'duration': 2000,
                 'easing': 'swing',
                 'hash': false
             });
        }
    });
});
```

What I'm running into is that because I don't have an `event.preventDefault` to stop the default browser action of jumping to the target, my page is jumping to my form as it is fading in.

I'd like to scroll the page *after* the form is fully shown.

If I use `event.preventDefault()`, the page will not scroll at all. Which makes sense since at that point I am telling it not to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of complicating it with yet another library, just use Velocity's [`scroll`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#scroll) command to scroll to the required position, for example:

```
//...
complete: function (form) {
    $(form).velocity('scroll', { duration: 2000, easing: "swing" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely overlooked the fact velocity could handle that. I was even using `scrollTop`. Too close to the project I suppose.